# Executable is not signed after installed via MSI

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, signtool

We have an application that requires the user to be an admin to run.  So, in the `app.manifest` we have set up

`<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

We have a key to sign our assemblies with, which I have been able to use for signing the MSI and the executable of our application.  The application's executable is signed via `signtool.exe` in the post build event for the project.

If I look in the bin directory, the executable is indeed signed correctly, but after it is packaged into the `msi` and installed on another machine, the executable is no longer signed.

This would normally not be a huge issue except that we require admin priviledges, so when the user gets the UAC prompt, it displays an unknown publisher.

How can I get the executable to be signed after it is packaged into an MSI?

Comment: Create a setup.exe instead of a .msi, sign it.

Comment: MSI can go away and die for all I care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer on an obscure blog.

When the MSI is compiled, it does not pull from the bin directory, it pulls from the obj directory. Basically, I had been signing the wrong executable.

Comment: Can you post the URL to the blog?

Comment: This had just enough information to have me realise what was wrong with my installer. Thank you!